# How to use ParseLiveQuery with swift 3?

Tags: parse-platform, swift3, cocoapods

How to use ParseLiveQuery with swift 3? Using CocoaPods.

Answer (score -1):

**Step 1:**

Install the cocoaPod first.

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'ParseLiveQuery', '~> 1.1'
end
```

Then run a `pod install` inside your terminal, or from CocoaPods.app.

**Step 2:** As per docs

The `LiveQuery` client interface is based around the concept of Subscriptions. You can register any `PFQuery` for live updates from the associated live query server, by simply calling `subscribe()` on a query:

```
let myQuery = Message.query()!.where(....)
let subscription: Subscription<Message> = myQuery.subscribe()
```

Where Message is a registered subclass of `PFObject`.

Once you've subscribed to a query, you can handle events on them, like so:

```
subscription.handleEvent { query, event in
    // Handle event
}
```

Make use of the Swift 3 example if you get stuck:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX/tree/master/Examples/LiveQueryDemo